# How to set viewer.setThemingcolor upon multiple instances, without causing refresh of loader per instance?

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

I want to set a color upon a material, however setThemingColor(dbId,color,model) causer my viewer to refresh each time I add an instance. This is a problem since I have a lot of instances which have to be set.

Is there any functions which I can use to stop the viewer to reload, add the whole list of ids which I want to set to the color and then do a refresh of the viewer?

That is, with a list of 2000 ids which should have that color, I get one update instead of 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Model#setThemingColor( dbId, color )` instead, then tell the viewer to reload scene after all colors are set up. Here is the code snippet for you:

```
let selSet = viewer.getAggregateSelection();
for(let i=0; i<selSet.length; i++) {
    const model = selSet[i].model;
    const selection = selSet[i].selection;

    selection.forEach(( dbId ) => {
        model.setThemingColor( dbId, color );
    });
}

viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the problem.